# Custom WinRT app running during lock screen (instead of default Slide show)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, screen-lock

Any chance to make it possible to build special **WinRT** application that would run in lock screen mode on **Windows 8** like it "works" for default *Slide show* option setting?

[image: Slide show setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do things with Badges, such as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779720.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700416.aspx). Unfortunately, I don't think you can do exactly what you are asking, aside from possibly disabling the Lock Screen and building a facsimile of your own, though I don't know to what extent this will be allowed in the store, and will likely be largely up to the users settings with regards to things like working on battery or not.

Comment: Well, on the page under the first link that you gave there is more or less clear statement that "The Windows 8 lock screen serves three basic purposes:... 3. Displays lightweight information to the user." - and *lightweight* is a the key here, I suppose. So it seems like an as designed restriction. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. The [Win 8.1 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.aspx) lets you provide an rss feed of images that fuel the lockscreen slideshow, but you don't appear to be able to provide your own app to replace the lockscreen background.

I agree this would be really useful. The lockscreen could be used to turn your device into an ambient data source. For example, custom slideshows, streams of social network posts & pictures, graphs tracking stats you care about (stocks, server load etc.), streams of trending headlines etc.

Comment: Yep, exactly! Hope that MS rethink this part of the UX in the (near) future.

Comment: Me too. A tablet or computer should be useful even when you're not actively interacting with it.

Comment: Users often expect their tablets to have long battery life; running arbitrary applications when the system is idle tends to prevent that.

Comment: Indeed it does. However, if that application is using the screen, then the user is aware of the power draw.

Comment: PS - Eric, you seem to allude to the problem of naive developers hogging battery life, and naive users squandering it. Android has 2 solutions to those problems that are relevant here: a) it shows the user per-app power usage, and b) it lets the user choose to run Daydreams only when attached to external power. (A Daydream is an Android app that runs when the system is idle)